# GUI dynamically adding check boxes faster?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm trying to make a GUI that will search a text file of a codebook.The user will type in keywords and the results will be printed out in a `QScrollArea` with a checkbox next to it. I have working code for all of it but my problem is, sometimes there can be close to 1200 check box's that are added and it really slows everything down and the GUI freezes for around 4 seconds. Is there a way to be able to add all of these check boxes but not have the whole thing freeze while it is adding them? I have looked at how quickly the results come back and even for over 1000 results it comes back in about 0.32 seconds. My thought is dynamically adding widgets is what is slowing it down. Thank you for any advice and your time

**Code explanation**

Below I have posted the function that does what I was explaining. Basically every time a letter is added in the search bar it will call the function `search_results`. I have another class called `codeBook` that does all of my actual search logic and then returns the results as a `list` and assigns it to the `results` variable. Then it loops through `results` and prints out the check boxes.

**Current Working Code**

```
def search_results(self):

    try:
        start_x = 10
        start_y = 10
        test_input = self.findChild(QScrollArea, "Results_choice_box")
        Search_data = self.findChild(QLineEdit, "SearchBox")
        grid = self.findChild(QGridLayout, "gridLayout")
        Search_data = Search_data.text()



        if len(Search_data) > 4:

            search = codeBook()
            results = search.codebook_search(Search_data,self.CodeBook)            
            self.remove_previous_from_window()
            for i in range(0,len(results)-1):
                checkBox = QCheckBox(results[i], self)
                checkBox.setObjectName("checkBox__" +str(i))
                grid.addWidget(checkBox,start_y + (i*10),start_x)
                checkBox.stateChanged.connect(self.update_text_window)
        else:
            self.remove_previous_from_window()

    except:
        pass
```

Comment: You might want to use a `QTableVIew` and a custom `QAbstractTableModel` or `QStandardItemModel` instead.

Comment: Thank you for the advice I will have to look into those.